# Preferred Azure Service to run python script with an endpoint in a scalable way

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-machine-learning-service

I wrote a heavy calculation script in Python and tested it using a Flask API. It receives JSON and returns JSON.
Now we are looking to run the heavy calculation in Azure, but we are not sure which service to use. I have been trying to integrate it into the Azure Machine Learning Studio, but I feel like it is meant to be used by a complete machine learning model rather than just a python script.
What we need is a scalable way to run our heavy calculation that is accessible through an endpoint. It should be compatible with Azure ml studio in some way, if possible. A database, which kind has not been decided yet, might be added later on.
What would be the preferred service?

I tried integrating the python scripts in the Azure machine learning studio. We expected this to be the appropriate service for this purpose, but are now wondering if it is the right choice after all.

Answer (score 1):

I used the azure function app for using generic algorithm. Here, i created a function app, upon sending post request to function URL with data it gives the model output result. The model result is achieved by using azure ML endpoints where your model can be registered and created one realtime-endpoints where the `POST` request raised on it.

Here the steps to follow,
First, you need to registry your model in azure ML.

create new ML workspace  > launch ML studio.
[image: model register]

After registering model go to deploy as shown in below

[image]

select real-time endpoint and start configure the details asked.

next select authentication as key as below
[image]

At environment  section you need to add the source file which needed to be executing when request comes from client.
You refer below documentation how to register model and endpoint creation.
[Model registering and endpoint creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-studio)

after creating endpoint you will get rest api url as shown below

[image]
next you need to get key for authentication while making request.

Enter below command according your configuration in azure CLI to get the key

```
az ml online-endpoint get-credentials --name <your endpoint name> --resource-group <your resource grp> --workspace-name <ML workspace name> -o tsv --query primaryKey
```

After getting key save it.

Create function app in azure with your subscription and resource group.
[image]
After creating the function initial there will be no function in functions tab as shown below,
here for me since i deployed function before it is showing.
[image]

Follow are steps to deploy fucntion in visual code.
Go to extensions > search for azure function install it.

after installation you will find  azure symbol bottom left.

[image]

Go to azure tab, there as shown above there is one option to create function.
click on it and create function with `HTTP Trigger`, give the name of the function and
authorization level as `anonymous`.

After successfully created the function you will get a `__init__.py`and project structure as below.

[image]

By default the code will be as below in `**init**.py.

[image]`Replace that code with the below code.
Here is the place where you can add your generic script and get results from model. You can modify it in your own needs and call the ML endpoint url.

```
import  logging
import  urllib.request
import  json
import  os
import  ssl
import azure.functions as  func
def  allowSelfSignedHttps(allowed):#bypass the server certificate verification on client side
    if  allowed  and  not  os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and  getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
        allowSelfSignedHttps(True)
def  getmodelres(data):
    body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
    endpointurl = 'https://xxxx.centralindia.inference.ml.azure.com/score'
    endpoint_api_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"  # Replace this with the key or token you obtained
    print(api_key)
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ endpoint_api_key)}
    req = urllib.request.Request(endpointurl, body, headers)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = response.read()
        print(result)
        return  result
    except  urllib.error.HTTPError as  error:
        print("The request failed with status code: " + str(error.code))# Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
        print(error.info())
        print(error.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
        return  error.info()
        
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    data = req.get_json()
    name = getmodelres(data)
    if  name:
        return  func.HttpResponse(f"Model result, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return  func.HttpResponse("This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass  in the request body for a personalized response."
        status_code=200)
```

Next give your endpoint url and endpoint key in the script which you got for endpoint creation.

[image: upload]

After updating the code there is option called deploy as shown in image.
click on that and select `subscription id`,`resource group` and `azure function`  you created before in azure.
That starts the deployment.

Then go to your app function in azure, there you can find deployed functions under function tab click on it it.
You will get details as below.
There you can get function url.
[image]

After deploying then test the function URL as `POST` request with body having input data to model in json format.

I tested this in postman with azure function url .
You can see the result here i sent post request to function url and body having data, which is input to model.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply! I definitely considered using Azure Functions but since it is a rather large application and since scalability is very important I opted for Azure Kubernetes Service. This way I create and upload an image of the code instead of linking the code to Azure directly.