# It is possible to generate SAS Token for a blob using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my pipeline, I am generating a csv file in storage account. Now I need to get the SAS token of this csv file and add to a parameter. (I need to send this SAS token as a JSON response to some API).

So, I would like to know is it possible to generate SAS Token for a given blob in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

Using azure function you can write the code to generate sas token for the given file.

- First create azure python function with http trigger and below code.
- Follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75938689/preferred-azure-service-to-run-python-script-with-an-endpoint-in-a-scalable-way/76001825#76001825) thread for creating azure functions.
- After creating function, remove default code paste the below python code.
- import  logging
  import  datetime
  import  json
  import  azure.functions  as  func
  from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas

  def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
  storage_connection_string  =  "Your storage account connection string"
  container_name  =  "your container name"
  path  =  req.params['path']
  js_blob  =  json.loads(req.params['blob'])
  blob_path  =  path  +  js_blob[0]['name']
  print(blob_path)
  logging.info(blob_path)
  try:
  blob_service_client  =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string)
  container_client  =  blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
  #blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)
  sas_token  =  generate_blob_sas(
  account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
  container_name=container_name,
  blob_name=blob_path,
  account_key=blob_service_client.credential.account_key,
  permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True), # Set the desired permissions (read, write, etc.)
  expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() +  datetime.timedelta(hours=1) # Set the desired expiration time)

  ```
             return  func.HttpResponse(
                 body=f'{{ "SasToken": "{sas_token}" }}',
                 status_code=200,
                 mimetype='application/json')

      except  Exception  as  ex:
           logging.error('Error generating SAS token', exc_info=True)
      return  func.HttpResponse(status_code=500)
  ```

Here, you provide storage account connection string and container name, then copy function url and save it.

Upon `GET` requesting to this function with file details and path,
`sas` token is generated and returned.

In adf, I used used copy activity to generate csv file to the given path in container.

The path is given using pipeline parameter as shown below.

[image]

- Next, In sink dataset , parameter is created called **filepath** with default value and giving that to file path.

[image]

[image]

- In sink properties of copy activity, the pipeline parameter is passed in **filepath** as shown below.

[image]

- After copy activity, **Get Metadata** activity is used with the same output dataset and configuration as below.
  Since you need to create sas for generated file.

[image]

- Add **Child items**  in field list which is used to send them to azure functions.
- Next, add web activity with `GET` method and below code in url field.
- @concat('<Your_function_app_url>?path=',pipeline().parameters.destination,'&','blob=',activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems)

This code makes the url with parameters `path` and `blob`.
path is being pipeline parameter and blob is list of csv files.

After executing the pipeline below are outputs.

Get Metadata :

[image]

Here you can see the child items is in list, this is handled in azure function.
since there is one item it accessed directly with index,
if many items are there you loop through the list and create sas token to file you want by passing extra parameter in azure function url.

Web activity:

[image]

The sas token came from azure function as response can be used in any activity further.